# Symfony2 Application : Host database only

Tags: mysql, symfony, cloud

So I want to create this application using Symfony2. I don't want to host it online but I want to work on a database online (Cloud of Mysql or something similar). Is that possible ? if yes, how can I configure the parameters.ini file ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by simply providing the right parameters in the `parameter.yml` file.

For example:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    database_driver:    pdo_mysql
    database_host:      cloud.service.com
    database_name:      your_personnal_db
    database_user:      your_user
    database_password:  your_password
```

You also need to make sure your server can access the database.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database